# change of conditions in recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

First of all this is an assignment so I don't want a complete solution :)

I'm going to calculate the value of a deck in the Cardgame blackjack.

Rules are *all* Aces are 1 or 11.

suppose my hand is: (Ace, 5), My hand is now 16. Next card is a 6, my hand is now (Ace, 5,6) 22 but the ace that I already calculated before must now change to one so my hand is at 12.

my Hand datatype is defined recursive by

```
data Hand = Empty | Add Card Empty
```

so calculate a hand with fixed values are done by

```
valueOfHand (Add c h) = cardValue c + valueOfHand h
```

What's the pattern to change the values that appeared before?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `type Hand = [Card]`? That would make it easier to solve this in an idiomatic way.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't know it was defined this way in the supplied files :)

Comment: I have no idea what "all Aces are 1 exclusive or 11." is supposed to mean.

Comment: Your `Hand` type is essentially a list anyway. I would look at the `Monad` instance of `List`(`[]`) and use it's nondeterminism to check all possible readings of your aces and then pick the value of your hand, whatever that is (there will be more than one, especially if you somehow manage to draw more than one ace).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz lets say I have two aces in my Hand both must be 1 or 11 they can't have separate values

Comment: I still have no idea on what you're talking about. More examples.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I have the hand (2, Ace, Ace) It cannot be the value of 2 + 11(Ace) + 1(Ace) it must be either 2 + 11(Ace) + 11(Ace) or 2 + 1(Ace) + 1(Ace)

Comment: Either being what, exactly? A list of two possible values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your class has already covered the list monad, but I think that's the most natural way to solve this. So instead of having `cardValue` return a simple value, it should return a non-deterministic value that lists all the possible values that the card might have, i.e.

```
cardValue :: Card -> [Int]
cardValue Ace = [1, 11]
cardValue Two = [2]
...
```

`valueOfHand` will then have two parts: one that computes a list of all possible hand values and another that selects the best, legal hand.

Let me know if this is enough for you to solve it or if you need more hints.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you indicate in the comments, `Ace`s may only have one value per hand (so a hand of three `Ace`s is 3 or 33), then it makes sense to define your `valueOfHand :: Hand -> Integer` function in a way that first totals up non-`Ace` cards and then handles the `Ace`s.

I would expect such a function would be based around something like this:

`valueOfHand Empty = 0`

`valueOfHand h = valueOfAces (filter (\c -> c == Ace) h) (filter (\c -> c /= Ace) h)`

For some function `valueOfAces :: Hand -> Hand -> Integer`.

Comment: Instead of writing `valueOfAces (filter (\c -> c == Ace) h) (filter (\c -> c /= Ace) h)` you should write `uncurry valueOfAces (span (==Ace) h)`